# Using Member Variables That Are Private c++

Tags: c++

I added all my code.

The exact problem I am facing is when I make the member variables `private` in the `game.h` file I get an error in the game.cpp file that says `n p h` are all private members of game.h. in `Xcode`.

But when I compile the program from the command line it compiles fine with no errors.

I am trying to understand if I am doing something wrong or is this up to standards the way I am doing this?

This is main.cpp

```
#include "game.h"


int main() {

   game g("Female", "Magic", true, 21, 5, 120);

    std::cout << "These are the things every game needs to be a game" << '\n';

    std::cout << g << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "game.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const game& g) {
    return s << &g.n << ' ' << &g.p  << ' ' <<  &g.h;
}
```

This is my composite class

```
#include <iostream>

#include "npc.h"
#include "pc.h"
#include "health.h"

class game {
private:
    npc n;
    pc p;
    health h;

public:
    game(const npc& init_n, const pc& init_p, const health& init_h):
    n(init_n),
    p(init_p),
    h(init_h)
    {}


    game(std::string gen, std::string abil, bool use, int lvl, int h, int arm) :
    n(gen, abil),
    p(use, lvl),
    h(h, arm)
    {
    }

 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const game& g) {
         g.n.output(s);
         g.p.output(s);
         g.h.output(s);
        return s;
 }

     npc get_n() { return n; }
     pc get_p() { return p; }
     health get_h() { return h; }

     void set_n(npc init_n) { n = init_n; }
     void set_p(pc init_p) { p = init_p ; }
     void set_h(health init_h) { h = init_h; }
};
```

Here is a class

```
#include <iostream>

class health {
private:
    int hp;
    int armor;

public:
    health(int init_hp, int init_armor) :
    hp(init_hp),
    armor(init_armor)
    {
    }

public:
    void output(std::ostream& s) const { s << "Characters have this amount of hit points "<< hp << " and an armor rating of " << armor << "\n";  }

    };
```

Here is a class

```
class pc {
private:
    bool user;
    int level;

public:
    pc(bool init_user, int init_level) :
    user(init_user),
    level(init_level)
    {
    }

public:
    void output(std::ostream& s) const { s << "A player character has at least "<< user << " user and a level of " << level << '\n';  }

};
```

Here is a class

```
#include <iostream>

class npc {
private:
    std::string gender;
    std::string ability;

public:
    npc(std::string init_gender, std::string init_ability) :
    gender(init_gender),
    ability(init_ability)
    {
    }

public:
  void output(std::ostream& s) const { s << "A non player character has a gender of "<< gender << " and an ability of " << ability << '\n';  }

};
```

Comment: ...are you *using* your getters and setters? C++ doesn't automatically turn attribute access into getter or setter calls.

Comment: Show the code you are having trouble with

Comment: The assignments in your setters are the wrong way round.

Comment: off topic but it's good practice to mark your getters as const; eg: `npc get_n() const { return n; }`

Comment: I am showing the code I am having a problem with. Yes I rearranged the getters and setters. Still only works when I change it to public

Comment: And why was this question down voted? Also I think I am using getters and setters. lol

Comment: Have you defined the assignment operator for your npc, pc, and health classes?

Comment: By definition, private members cannot be accessed directly. And then you want to access them directly. You are simply contradicting yourself. Perhaps the down vote is due to the ridiculousness.

Comment: Lol so the down vote is for not knowing what I am doing. Ya god forbid someone ask a question about something they are not very familiar with.

Comment: @NDiaz It is just a possible theory that may explain where the down vote comes from, in response to what you've ask in your comment. It is not a good phenomenon any way. After all, questions arise from unfamiliarity, and this site is for asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made several errors - a typo is the reason for your problem.
The function is not allowed to access those members because it is not a friend of the class.
The friend is (correctly) `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const game& g)`
while you defined a function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const game g)`, note the missing ampersand.

Also, your accessors should be const, and return a const reference.
Ie,

```
 npc const& get_n() const { return n; }
 pc const& get_p() const { return p; }
 health const& get_h() const { return h; }
```

Your manipulators change the wrong variables! You change the ones passed to the function instead of the members of that class.... However, it is highly questionable that you add direct manipulators for the three private members. You must view your class as some abstract object and define operators that work on that object. If you just give direct access to all it's members than there is little left of the object orientation idea behind using a class with private members (this would still be ten times better than making them public though!)

Finally, just a coding style hint. It is common practice to use CamelCase names for custom classes (ie, class Game), and you're better of adding a prefix to your private members to distinguish them from function parameters. Often people use the prefix `m_`. You really should use complete english words too (not abbreviations, let alone single characters).

This would turn your code into, say...

```
class Game {
  private:
    Npc m_npc;
    Pc m_pc;
    Health m_health;

  public:
    Game(Npc const& npc, Pc const& pc, Health const& health) :
        m_npc(npc), m_pc(pc), m_health(health) { }
```

etc.

Comment: I appreciate you answering. But this does not fix my problem. A lot of good information though. In fact I have found that by compiling from the terminal in osx the program runs fine. It won't compile in xcode for some reason though and can not access the variables when they are private. I realize I don't have `&` on `game&` because it says redefinition of <<. But when I move it to &g.n << ' ' << &g.p  << ' ' <<  &g.h; I can run it fine from the terminal. I dont know if thats acceptable or not.

Comment: Your operator<< friend function should look like: `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Game const& game) { return os << game.m_npc << ' ' << game.m_pc  << ' ' <<  game.m_health; }`. If you still have compile errors then please provide a complete, compileable test-code snippet; I corrected everything that you posted so far.

Comment: I updated my code to show you it all. The way I have it it compiles fine from command line but main.cpp says that `n p h` are private members of game.h.

Comment: What you changed has two instantiations of the operator<<. I suspect you only want to keep the one declared in the header. Thus, *delete* the one in game.cpp. After that change I could compile and link it (and run it).

Comment: If something still complains about n, p and h being private when accessing them from the operator<< defined in class game, then I suspect a broken compiler ;). There is no such error anymore in this code.

Comment: LOL. Thanks man. The whole time it was because I did not need `game.cpp` as you said. Thanks for sticking it out and helping me. I must ask. Is my code bad the way it is? When you mentioned accessing them directly which is ten times better then making them public what did you mean? what part of my code illustrated that?